# Какая dll содержит данные строки?

Tags: dll

Какая стандартная dll windows содержит данные строки?

```
Configuring Windows Updates
d%% complete.
Do not turn off your computer
```

Они появляются при установке обновлений

Comment: Берете FAR, ищете все файлы *.dll в нужном каталоге с нужными строками...

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что задача, сформулированная в вопросе, не относится к программированию или системному администрированию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C:\Windows\servicing\CbsMsg.dll